# Foreign wp_users ID in custom plugin DB table?

Tags: plugin-development, mysql

I'm creating a custom plugin that creates four custom tables when the plugin is activated. I have two tables that is using 2 foreign keys in one table and four foreign keys in the other. If I don't include the `FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES wp_users(id)` in the code then the tables are created perfectly, everything works as expected but I need the foreign key for the user ID for both `$questions_table` and `$forms_table`.

I've tried `FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES $users_table(id)` and `FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES $wpdb->users(id)`. I also tried changing "id" to uppercase which didn't work either.

```
    global $wpdb;
    global $foo_plugin;

    $form_status_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'foo_form_status';
    $form_type_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'foo_form_type';
    $questions_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'foo_questions';
    $forms_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'foo_forms';

    $users_table = $wpdb->users;
    
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

    $form_status_sql = "CREATE TABLE $form_status_table (
        id mediumint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        name tinytext NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    ) $charset_collate;";

    $form_type_sql = "CREATE TABLE $form_type_table (
        id mediumint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        type tinytext NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    ) $charset_collate;";

    $questions_sql = "CREATE TABLE $questions_table (
        id mediumint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        date_created datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL,
        user_id bigint NOT NULL,
        questions mediumtext NOT NULL,
        draft tinyint NOT NULL,
        foo_form_type_id mediumint(10) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (id),
        FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES wp_users(id),
        FOREIGN KEY (foo_form_type_id) REFERENCES $form_type_table(id)
    ) $charset_collate;";

    $forms_sql = "CREATE TABLE $forms_table (
        id mediumint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        user_id bigint NOT NULL,
        draft tinyint NOT NULL,
        app_id mediumint(10) NOT NULL,
        foo_form_type_id mediumint(10) NOT NULL,
        foo_form_status_id mediumint(10) NOT NULL,
        foo_questions_id mediumint(10) NOT NULL,
        form_title tinyint NOT NULL,
        date_submitted datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL,
        applicant_info mediumtext NOT NULL,
        appilication_info mediumtext NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (id),
        FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES wp_users(id),
        FOREIGN KEY (foo_form_type_id) REFERENCES $form_type_table(id),
        FOREIGN KEY (foo_form_status_id) REFERENCES $form_status_table(id),
        FOREIGN KEY (foo_questions_id) REFERENCES $questions_table(id)
    ) $charset_collate;";

    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php';
    dbDelta( $form_status_sql );
    dbDelta( $form_type_sql );
    dbDelta( $questions_sql );
    dbDelta( $forms_sql );

    add_option( 'foo_plugin', $foo_plugin );
}
```

Comment: The `ID` column of the `wp_users` table is indeed capitalized. But apart from that, as a bit of a shot in the dark, I think it could possibly be a difference in column formats - `wp_users`'s `ID` column is `BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED`, while the foreign key in your code specifies no size and is signed.

Comment: Hmm. Ok, thanks! I didn't realize that about the column. I'll try something else with that in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked it out! Big thanks to [bosco](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/25324/bosco) for pointing out the format for the WP User ID column, that helped out so much!

In addition to changing the formatting for the ID columns, I changed the name of the ID columns in the $questions_sql and $forms_sql to be something that wasn't user_id.

```
global $wpdb;
global $foo_plugin;

$form_status_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'foo_form_status';
$form_type_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'foo_form_type';
$questions_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'foo_questions';
$forms_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'foo_forms';

$users_table = $wpdb->users;

$charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

$form_status_sql = "CREATE TABLE $form_status_table (
    id mediumint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name tinytext NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (id)
) $charset_collate;";

$form_type_sql = "CREATE TABLE $form_type_table (
    id mediumint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    type tinytext NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (id)
) $charset_collate;";

$questions_sql = "CREATE TABLE $questions_table (
    id mediumint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    date_created datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL,
    admin_id bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    questions mediumtext NOT NULL,
    draft tinyint NOT NULL,
    foo_form_type_id mediumint(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (admin_id) REFERENCES wp_users(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (foo_form_type_id) REFERENCES $form_type_table(id)
) $charset_collate;";

$forms_sql = "CREATE TABLE $forms_table (
    id mediumint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    author_id bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    draft tinyint NOT NULL,
    app_id mediumint(10) NOT NULL,
    foo_form_type_id mediumint(10) NOT NULL,
    foo_form_status_id mediumint(10) NOT NULL,
    foo_questions_id mediumint(10) NOT NULL,
    form_title tinyint NOT NULL,
    date_submitted datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL,
    applicant_info mediumtext NOT NULL,
    appilication_info mediumtext NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (author_id) REFERENCES wp_users(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (foo_form_type_id) REFERENCES $form_type_table(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (foo_form_status_id) REFERENCES $form_status_table(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (foo_questions_id) REFERENCES $questions_table(id)
) $charset_collate;";

require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php';
dbDelta( $form_status_sql );
dbDelta( $form_type_sql );
dbDelta( $questions_sql );
dbDelta( $forms_sql );

add_option( 'foo_plugin', $foo_plugin );
```